# ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was trying out hyperledger.

```
sauron@sauron-Lenovo-Z51-70 ~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar $ ./startFabric.sh 

# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Removing network net_basic

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com   
orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
Pulling ca.example.com (hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest)...
ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest not found
```

I was trying out the fabric-samples as given in the tutorial http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/write_first_app.html
I am getting this log when I run ./startFabric.sh.
Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Pull `fabric-ca` from docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger.

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0-preview
```

Tag it as latest:

```
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0-preview hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
```

Then run:

```
docker images
```

and `hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest` will be there.

Comment: it worked for me, thanks a lot... I see that no one thanked you ;)